# DAX =YEAR(Payments[Date Payment Recorded]) cannot be determined in current context

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a simple PowerPivot containing 2 tables.  The payments table (containing many records for the claims table) holds a date value for payments.  I have added 'payment date', 'payee' to the row labels, and sum of payment value to the Values.  I want to display the payment date as the year only, so I created a new Measure called 'Payment Year' with the following DAX expression:

```
=YEAR(Payments[Date Payment Recorded])
```

however I continually get the error

> The value for column 'Date Payment Recorded' in table 'Payments' cannot be determined in the current context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry new to PPivot and DAX!  answer = Create a column on the PowerPivot tables for the year `YEAR(Payments[date payment recorded])`, rename the column heading and then it's available to be used in the PivotTable.

As I understand this, DAX / PowerPivot cannot GroupBy a calculated measure.  I'm no expert (so may be wrong) but the calculated measures should be seen as 'Values' not for manipulating the 'grouping' etc.

Comment: Agree with @Tim-Windsor. Measures are meant to aggregate in some way. What you are looking for is the calculated column that Tim describes. This will give you the year for the [date payment recorded] for each row.